# Combing CoffeeScript output files and minimizing them in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, minify, coffeescript

I am using WorkBench to create CoffeScript files in VS2010. IS there a way I can combine the compiled js files into 1 file and minimize that file to include in my view?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 2):

I had a quick look at WorkBench and found it to be much less appealing and functional than "Chirpy" which simply *does the job*. See http://chirpy.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this article http://mkramar.blogspot.com/2011/08/css-and-javascript-minify-and-combine.html

It is a hand-crafted solution but somehow I liked it. Could be improved more, as it uses a custom compressor but it simply concats and compresses the static files into a single one using an Html helper.